# cordova geolocation (3.0.0) does not ask for GPS permission

Tags: cordova, permissions, geolocation

I build an app using Cordova and Geolocation plugin, version 3.0.0. The plugin seems to be installed without error.

I build the .apk and install it in a device. The message I get is:

```
Do you want to install this application? It does not require any special access.
```

When I run the application for the first time, this pop-up appears:

```
Allow app to access this device's location?
```

It's been a while since I had my last build using a previous Geolocation plugin (I think, version 2.4.3), but I remember that it said during installation that it required GPS access, without asking for permission when running the app. During installation, it was asking for GPS permission with a message like:

```
Do you want to install this application? It will get access to:

access to precise location (GPS and network-based)
```

Now, plugin seems more like a web-API (HTML5) geolocation instead of a native GPS plugin. In addition, cordova won't let me use a previous version because of cordova-plugin compatibility issues.

My question is:
Is there a problem with the plugin installation? Or is it really the new geolocation version like this, asking for permission during runtime like HTML5 geolocation does?

Comment: *Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.* [look here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)